# dwoo template variables inside JavaScript?

Tags: php, javascript, templates, variables, dwoo

i have this code.

```
{if $loginUrl}
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newwindow;
    var intId;
    function login() {
        var  screenX    = typeof window.screenX != 'undefined' ? window.screenX : window.screenLeft,
             screenY    = typeof window.screenY != 'undefined' ? window.screenY : window.screenTop,
             outerWidth = typeof window.outerWidth != 'undefined' ? window.outerWidth : document.body.clientWidth,
             outerHeight = typeof window.outerHeight != 'undefined' ? window.outerHeight : (document.body.clientHeight - 22),
             width    = 500,
             height   = 270,
             left     = parseInt(screenX + ((outerWidth - width) / 2), 10),
             top      = parseInt(screenY + ((outerHeight - height) / 2.5), 10),
             features = (
                'width=' + width +
                ',height=' + height +
                ',left=' + left +
                ',top=' + top
              );

        newwindow=window.open('{$loginUrl}','Login by facebook',features);

        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    }
</script>
{/literal}
{/if}
```

It is dwoo templates, i wonder how can i use my dwoo variables inside javascript? im trying to do it just at you can see at the code, but it doesnt work. I need to warp my code between {literal} so it can work.

Comment: Don't know anything about dwoo, but assuming it's a server side thing, probably something like `val somevar = "{$somevar}";`

Answer (score 4):

Remove the {literal} tags. Dwoo is smart enough about that to avoid messing up your javascript unless you use object literals in one line.

To be exact, { followed by any space, tab or line break will not be parsed by Dwoo. The only problem is if you do something like :

```
{foo: "bar"}
```

In which case you have a few options to prevent Dwoo parsing:

```
\{foo: "bar"} // escape the {
{ foo: "bar"} // add a space so it doesn't match it
{literal}{foo: "bar"}{/literal} // wrap with literal, but then you can't use vars inside again

// or expand it to use multiple lines, which is usually more readable anyway
{
    foo: "bar"
}
```

Answer (score -1):

You can just do `{/literal}{$the_varible}{literal}` to insert variables inside the literal tags.

Comment: Not wrong, but not the complete story either, and definitely not ideal, so I'd like to bump my answer to the top since the guy who asked is off the grid. No offense I hope.

Answer (score -2):

Hm.. found a "fix" but it is hardcoded and there should be something better:

```
    {if $loginUrl}
{literal}
<script type="text/javascript">
    var newwindow;
    var intId;
    function login() {
        var  screenX    = typeof window.screenX != 'undefined' ? window.screenX : window.screenLeft,
             screenY    = typeof window.screenY != 'undefined' ? window.screenY : window.screenTop,
             outerWidth = typeof window.outerWidth != 'undefined' ? window.outerWidth : document.body.clientWidth,
             outerHeight = typeof window.outerHeight != 'undefined' ? window.outerHeight : (document.body.clientHeight - 22),
             width    = 500,
             height   = 270,
             left     = parseInt(screenX + ((outerWidth - width) / 2), 10),
             top      = parseInt(screenY + ((outerHeight - height) / 2.5), 10),
             features = (
                'width=' + width +
                ',height=' + height +
                ',left=' + left +
                ',top=' + top
              );

        newwindow=window.open({/literal}'{$loginUrl}'{literal},'Login by facebook',features);

        if (window.focus) {newwindow.focus()}
        return false;
    }
</script>
{/literal}
{/if}
```

Just.. ugly.